# Google Map API Key Fail using PHP with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I am using the following code to geocode address but hit their threshold.  The code works fine outside of this.  I signed up for the cloud services and enabled the free 60 day trial for the increased daily limit.  I added a KEY value you can see below and tacked on &KEY='.$KEY at the end of the $geocode variable to send the KEY but I am still getting the same error of cannot geocode I was getting after I hit the threshold.

What am I doing wrong with passing the KEY value?

```
<?php
require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

define("KEY", "my-api-key");

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT latitude,full_address,city,postal_code,matrix_unique_id FROM fort_property_res WHERE latitude IS NULL";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

// Initialize delay in geocode speed
$delay = 0;
// Iterate through the rows, geocoding each address
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $geocode_pending = true;

  while ($geocode_pending) {
    $adres=$row["full_address"].','.$row["city"].', FL '.$row["postal_code"];
    $address = urlencode($adres);
    $id = $row["matrix_unique_id"];
    $request_url = $base_url . "&address=" . urlencode($address);
     $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false&key='.$KEY);
     $output= json_decode($geocode);
     $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
     $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
     if ($latitude) {
      // successful geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      $coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;
      $coordinatesSplit = split(",", $coordinates);
      $lat = $latitude;
      $lng = $longitude;
     //die();

      $query = sprintf("UPDATE fort_property_res " .
             " SET latitude = '%s', longitude = '%s' " .
             " WHERE matrix_unique_id = '%s' LIMIT 1;",
             mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
             mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
             mysql_real_escape_string($id));
      $update_result = mysql_query($query);

      if (!$update_result) {
        die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
      }
    } else if (strcmp($status, "620") == 0) {
      // sent geocodes too fast
      $delay += 100000;
    } else {
      // failure to geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      echo "Address " . $address . " failed to geocode. ";
      echo "Received status " . $status . "
\n";
    }
    usleep($delay);
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `define`, you shouldn't have the `$` on the variable, try this:

```
$geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false&KEY='.KEY);
```

(Notice that `$KEY` is now `KEY` at the end of the URL)

Comment: Yes, I tried with both &KEY= and &key= just in case Google wanted it lower case and it still bombed out.  No such luck...I figured this would do the trick :-(

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco I mean the `$KEY` php variable you are using - you have used `define("KEY", "my-api-key");` to define it, but are trying to access it via `$KEY` instead of `KEY`.

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco Here is more information regarding `define`. Check the examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: Yes, I substitued the KEY as you mentioned as well...same situation.

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco Found in the Google Geocoding API docs: `Note: HTTPS is enforced for requests that include an API key.` (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#api_key)

Comment: AAAAhhhh, I thought that HAD to be it...nothing.  Same problem :-(